# Uk Post Code Regex

Tags: regex

Possible Duplicates
[Regex to validate UK Post Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559757/problem-with-regular-expressions-uk-post-code)

I Need a Regex syntax which accepts the posts codes like the following formates

```
CR03JP
cr03jp
CR0 3JP
cr0 3jp
```

what I have now is

```
 ^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$
```

which accepts `CR0 3JP` but rejects `cro3jp CR03JP`

I have tried the following also

```
/((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))/i
```

if this has been answered already please point me to the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex

```
^ ?(([BEGLMNSWbeglmnsw][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz][A-HK-Ya-hk-y][0-9][0-9]?)|(([ENWenw][0-9][A-HJKSTUWa-hjkstuw])|([ENWenw][A-HK-Ya-hk-y][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXYabehmnprvwxy])))) ?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}$
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use a 'case-insensitive modifier' for the regex, and then only deal with the normal upper-case letters?

Comment: Thanks for you instant reply's Prasanth's answer solved my prob

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you require 1 or 2 spaces in the middle

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$
                                                                ^^^
```

change this to `{0,2}` and it will also accept Postcodes without space in between. See [Limiting Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Also the `i` modifier is needed for case insensitive matching, like you used it in your second regex.